# window.opener is NULL with right click on link

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, window.opener, cross-origin-opener-policy

I'm using the javascript **window.opener** property to refresh the parent window in the child window.

The parent window cointains just a table with data and a link to the child window, when the child window is opened then executes a js function in the parent using the **window.opener** property, the js function in the parent refresh the table using ajax.

The problem is with **window.opener** because is NULL when the user open the link
using the right click (contextmenu).

Example:

### *parent.jsp*

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
              function refreshTable() {
                 // ajax code to refresh the #theTable table, not important for this question
              }
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <a href="/folder/child.jsp" target="_blank">OpenChild</a> 
       <table id="theTable">
           <tr>
            <td>...</td>
          </tr> 
       </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```

### *child.jsp*

```html
<html>
        <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready( function() {
                     // opener is NULL when child is opened with right click
                     window.opener.refreshTable();

                  });
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            ...          
        </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I know it is late but I leave this here for future use

add

```
rel="opener"
```

to the target="_blank" link

```
<a href="/folder/child.jsp" target="_blank" rel="opener">OpenChild</a>
```

The opener will be passed through the child page

based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

In the following cases, the browser does not populate window.opener, but leaves it null:

- The opener can be omitted by specifying rel=noopener on a link, or
  passing noopener in the windowFeatures parameter.
- From Firefox 79, windows opened because of links with a target of
  _blank don't get an opener, unless explicitly requested with rel=opener.
- Having a Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header with a value of
  same-origin prevents setting opener. Since the new window is loaded
  in a different browsing context, it won't have a reference to the
  opening window.

sidenote: btw there is no difference if you open a page with right or left click

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your requirements, you could always just set the `window.opener` in your `child.jsp` page:

```
window.opener="https://www.google.com/";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I just need some reference to the parent window object to refresh the table in the parent window, that is my requirement, when the user do the left click on the link everything works fine... but if the user do the right click ("open in a new tab") on the link then the reference to the parent is NULL in the child window.

Comment: @AndrewSullivan You're welcome.  So yeah, just set the `window.opener` value in child.jsp and then call `refreshtable()` and you should be fine.

Comment: I think that solution will not work because I need a reference to an instance of the window object, and with that assignement you just initializing a string property into the global window object and is not a reference to the parent window. Is just a string not a reference to the opener window.